# How to inject the key of each map entry into the corresponding value object with Jackson deserialization?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following json object.

```
{
  "items": {
    "item-1": {"type":"A", "desc": "blabla"},
    "item-2": {"type":"B", "desc": "blabla"},
    ...
  }
}
```

and I want to map this json object to the following java object.

```
public class MyObject {
  private final Map<String,Item> items;

  @JsonCreator
  public MyObject(@JsonProperty Map<String,Item> items) { ... }
  ...
}

class Item {
  private final string id;             <-- ideally could be initialized by the corresponding key in the map
  private final String type;
  private final String desc;

  public Item(@JsonProperty String id, @JsonProperty String type, @JsonProperty String desc) { ... }
}
```

The deserialization works only when I provide the following json object.

```
{
  "items": {
    "item-1": {"id":"item-1", "type":"A", "desc": "blabla"},
    "item-2": {"id":"item-2", "type":"B", "desc": "blabla"},
    ...
  }
}
```

That's not ideal (ie: redundancy -> error prone).

Is there a jackson annotation to solve this common pattern, or some other way? I failed to find something like `@JsonProperty(useKeyMap=true)`.

Update: I'm not interested by a solution where the id argument of the constructor is initialized to null.

Answer (score 0):

```
I have tried your example you need to put @Json creator annotation on your Items class constructor as well.

Below is the modified code.

class Item {

    private final String id;

    private final String type;

    private final String desc;

    @JsonCreator
    public Item( @JsonProperty("id")String id,   @JsonProperty("type")String type,  @JsonProperty("desc")String desc) {
        this.id = id;
        this.type = type;
        this.desc = desc;
    }
}

class MyObject {
    private final Map<String,Item> items;

    @JsonCreator
    public MyObject(@JsonProperty("items") Map<String, Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
```

It deserialises the json and if you will not provide the value of id then default it would be null.

Comment: Yes I know that's the default behavior, my question is more to avoid this null id in the constructor of the Item class when the id property is not provided in the json object. By the way, if you use the compiler option -parameters (javac) you don't need to specify the name of each argument in the constructor.

Comment: Then using @JsonCreator will actually help you to do like this: ` @JsonCreator
    public Item( @JsonProperty("type")String type,  @JsonProperty("desc")String desc) {
        //this.id = id;
        this.type = type;
        this.desc = desc;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for this, involving a custom Deserializer.  There is no real magic here (no handy annotation), but perhaps it will help.

```
@Test
public void test() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    Data data = mapper.readValue("{\"users\": {\"John\": {\"id\": 20}, \"Pete\": {\"id\": 30}}}", Data.class);

    assertEquals(20, data.users.get("John").id);
    assertEquals(30, data.users.get("Pete").id);
    assertEquals("John", data.users.get("John").name);
    assertEquals("Pete", data.users.get("Pete").name);
}

public static class Data {
    @JsonDeserialize(contentUsing = Deser.class)
    public Map<String, User> users;
}

public static class User {
    public String name;
    public int id;
}

public static class Deser extends JsonDeserializer<User> {

    @Override
    public User deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String name = ctxt.getParser().getCurrentName();

        User user = p.readValueAs(User.class);

        user.name = name;   // Fills the key in the value object!

        return user;
    }
}
```